# Is it possible to swap a hard drive from an HP TPN 119 laptop to a HP Stream laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems

I have an HP Stream laptop with no operating system on it. I tried to download a Windows operating system onto it from a USB flash drive. But it would not take it for some reason.

Someone told me that the hard drive might have been ruined due to a hard reset. I don’t know.

I do also have an HP TPN 119 laptop so both are Intel.

So can I take the hard drive out of the larger laptop and put it into the HP stream?

I’m not tech savvy FYI and my patience is very thin but not as thin as my wallet so I need to be able to do this myself please help?

Comment: A few observations: 1. When asking/answering or even just commenting please make proper sentences and paragraphs when applicable. Proofread before posting or [edit] it afterwards. 2. Technical questions need to be assertive and the issue should be succinctly but intelligibly described. *it would not take it for some reason* is meaningless. Please describe a) HOW you did the Windows installation media; b) HOW you tried to boot it and what happened (error messages, etc.). (...)

Comment: (...) 3. *someone told me that the hard drive might have been ruined due to a hard reset*... that someone probably don't know what they're talking about but, of course, it's possible to have a defective drive for whatever reason (unlikely to be because of whatever you mean by "hard reset", though) and that why we need proper diagnostics/troubleshooting. 4. The CPUs of the laptops is irrelevant. 5. Typically yes, we can swap drives BUT... The slim HP Stream line comes with NON-replaceable eMMC drive soldered on the motherboard; if it fails the laptop is trash; Finally, I'm sorry to be blunt (..

Comment: (...) but you must understand that if you need to ask this question - *can I take the hard drive out of the larger laptop and put it into the HP stream?* -, you aren't yet competent to do it, if that was possible which it isn't anyway. Please consult professional technical support if you must. That said, if you manage to [edit] the question with the information requested above then maybe all you need is to learn the method to install an OS in that machine, assuming the aforementioned eMMC hasn't really failed.

Comment: tried to download a Windows operating system onto it from a USB flash drive. But it would not take it for some reason." Windows may be hard to install. Download an OS that can be run **live** from USB, such as Ubuntu, https://www.fosslinux.com/895/how-to-create-ubuntu-live-usb-drive-in-windows.htm, and test if the PC works with that. If not, the PC likely needs repair.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not possible to do this. The Stream laptop is an "ultraportable" or very small laptop which usually has its storage, its "hard drive" soldered to the main board and as such is not capable of connecting another storage device inside the laptop to replace that without extensive soldering, some special skill with electronics, AND access to the specific replacement parts, which you will definitely not find inside the TPN 119 you are considering taking parts from.

So, to put it simply, no you cannot.